# Yahoo (YUI) vs Google (Closure) framework for testing on browsers and node.js

Tags: yui, closures, yahoo, yui3

It seems that YUI is very focused on providing all the same code for both browsers and node.js.

That's very powerful because now I can use the same tests on both ends and don't have to rewrite/relearn anything.

Is google also focusing on node.js when it comes to testing?

YUI has a very verbose documentation about how to use it, Closure seems to lack this kind of good support.

Is YUI a better library to use on both ends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that Google isn't really focusing on node.js, however, it seems that a few people are working on making it compatible.  A Google reveals the following:

- [node-goog](https://github.com/hsch/node-goog)
- [nclosure](https://github.com/gatapia/nclosure)
- [node-closure](https://github.com/lm1/node-closure)